# Getting empty .tar after creating it

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I want to create the .tar, but after creation inside of the tar is empty. Someone knows why?

Here is my code. What should I add here?

```
  grunt.registerTask('speak',function(){
    var tar = require('tar-fs');
    var fs = require('fs');

    //packing a directory 
    tar.pack('C:/Users/user/Desktop/yoo').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('my-test3.tar'));

});
```

Comment: It looks the same to the npm example [https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar-fs] , are you sure `'C:/Users/user/Desktop/yoo'` is not empty?

Comment: it is not empty.May be I missed something?

Comment: Pass a Windows-style path? `tar.pack('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\yoo')`

Comment: again the file is empty

Comment: I don't remember now, but maybe there is a problem with direct access links ... `Users` may be a direct access link

Comment: Have you test with another directory ?

Comment: I think there is no problem with directory,because I did a lot of things with the same directory and it is working.May be something like I can't copy file due to permission or something like that?